# React Native useEffect wrong logic implementation

Tags: react-native

I started several days ago to create my first app, I am not deep into the useEffect logic if somebody can optimize this code in the correct logic way i will learn a lot of it.

The issue in this code is fetchData it is called when apiToken and userId still null, surely on a wrong logic in how to use useEffect.
Thanks!

```
export const SitesScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isRefreshing, setIsRefreshing] = useState(false);
  const [apiToken, setApiToken] = useState(null);
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsRefreshing(true);
    await fetch(
      global.endpoint +
        '/sites/current-user-sites/' +
        userId +
        '?access-token=' +
        apiToken,
      {
        method: 'GET',
      },
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        if (responseJson.success) {
          setData(responseJson.data);
          console.log(responseJson);
        } else {
        }
        setLoading(false);
        setIsRefreshing(false);
        console.log(apiToken);
        console.log(userId);
      });
  };

  const getData = async () => {
    let deviceData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('device_data');
    deviceData = JSON.parse(deviceData);
    setApiToken(deviceData.access_token);
    setUserId(deviceData.id);
    console.log(deviceData);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData().then(response => {
      fetchData();
    });
  }, [apiToken, userId]);

  const renderItem = ({
    item,
    index,
  }: {
    item: IListItem,
    index: number,
  }): React.ReactElement => (
    <ListItem
      title={`${item.name}`}
      description={`${item.address + ', ' + item.number + ' - ' + item.city}`}
      onPress={() =>
        navigation.navigate('Details', {
          siteId: item.id,
        })
      }
    />
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={GlobalStyles.safeArea}>
      <TopNavigation
        title={evaProps => (
          <Text style={GlobalStyles.headerTitle}>Cantieri</Text>
        )}
        alignment="center"
      />
      <Divider />
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl refreshing={isRefreshing} onRefresh={fetchData} />
        }
        ItemSeparatorComponent={Divider}
        renderItem={renderItem}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue here isn't really with the way you are using useEffect but they fact that you are expecting the state for userId and api token to have their values set before the fetchData function is called.

React tries to reduce the number of renders that it makes by holding onto state changes for the next render because of the way you have your getData and FetchData separated its going to run both those functions and then update the state value on the next render.

So you can combine your two methods into one so you don't reference the state values but just reference the returned values. You could also use multiple useEffects for a super quick solution but I don't advise this since it will cause a second render every load, or I change your state variables to Refs like so:

```
export const SitesScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isRefreshing, setIsRefreshing] = useState(false);
  const apiToken = useRef(null);
  const userId = useRef(null);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsRefreshing(true);
    await fetch(
      global.endpoint +
        '/sites/current-user-sites/' +
        userId.current +
        '?access-token=' +
        apiToken.current,
      {
        method: 'GET',
      },
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        if (responseJson.success) {
          setData(responseJson.data);
          console.log(responseJson);
        } else {
        }
        setLoading(false);
        setIsRefreshing(false);
        console.log(apiToken);
        console.log(userId);
      });
  };

  const getData = async () => {
    let deviceData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('device_data');
    deviceData = JSON.parse(deviceData);
    apiToken.current = deviceData.access_token;
    apiToken.current = deviceData.id;
    console.log(deviceData);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData().then(response => {
      fetchData();
    });
  }, []);

  const renderItem = ({
    item,
    index,
  }: {
    item: IListItem,
    index: number,
  }): React.ReactElement => (
    <ListItem
      title={`${item.name}`}
      description={`${item.address + ', ' + item.number + ' - ' + item.city}`}
      onPress={() =>
        navigation.navigate('Details', {
          siteId: item.id,
        })
      }
    />
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={GlobalStyles.safeArea}>
      <TopNavigation
        title={evaProps => (
          <Text style={GlobalStyles.headerTitle}>Cantieri</Text>
        )}
        alignment="center"
      />
      <Divider />
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl refreshing={isRefreshing} onRefresh={fetchData} />
        }
        ItemSeparatorComponent={Divider}
        renderItem={renderItem}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Because refs don't cause re-renders this should work for what you are trying to do without causing multiple renders. Here is the documentation on useRef https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef .

Also Here is a link to the Caveats of useState that explain a little better what I was saying about updating state on next render. https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate-caveats

Comment: it work like a sharm :-) in effect what make me crazy was that first load didn't work but on rerender was working.

Comment: another idea, while device data i use through all the app it is possible to get one time on app load and then make it available to all pages without get it from storage each time?

Comment: Yeah I went through this when I was starting with React as well. Just need to remember that state is not instantly accessible after setting it. Also its way more performant to useRef if you don't need a value to redraw/re-render the screen because you are reducing the amount of renders your app will need to make.

Comment: Yeah what you are looking for to have the device data called only once in the lifecycle of the app is useContexts. Here is the link to the documentation for them.
https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsRefreshing(true);
    
    let deviceData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('device_data');
    deviceData = JSON.parse(deviceData);
    let token = deviceData.access_token;
    setApiToken(deviceData.access_token);
    let uId = deviceData.id;
    setUserId(deviceData.id);

    await fetch(
      global.endpoint +
        '/sites/current-user-sites/' +
        uId +
        '?access-token=' +
        token,
      {
        method: 'GET',
      },
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        if (responseJson.success) {
          setData(responseJson.data);
          console.log(responseJson);
        } else {
        }
        setLoading(false);
        setIsRefreshing(false);
        console.log(apiToken);
        console.log(userId);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: like this i can't use device_data for other calls.

Comment: YOu can use see it also set data in your states too

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this code

```
useEffect(() => {
    getData().then(response => {
      fetchData();
    });
  }, [apiToken, userId]);
```

you need to split this into 2 useEffects() as following:

```
export const SitesScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  ....
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (apiToken && userId) { // check validation of apiToken && userId
      fetchData();
    }
  }, [apiToken, userId]);
  ...
}
```

first `useEffect()` is called at the initial step, and the second one is called whenever `apiToken` and `userId` are changed.

Comment: This is definitely a solution to the problem. The issue I see with this as I stated in my answer is that this would cause two renders for each load. Most likely not noticed but depending on the list size that could be pretty expensive for performance.

Comment: Well.. `getData()` is only called at the initial step of SitesScreen component is mounted. and the second one is called whenever the dependency elements(apiToken, userId) are changed. so I don't think any such problem you mentioned

Comment: very interesting solution, i didn't think the possibility to split in two useEffect, the solution of Dusting works great anyway i will try even yours to  study it. thanks

Comment: Yeah the reason that it causes two renders is not because of the second useEffect it's because the first one with the empty array is called on mount and updates the state for apiToken and userId. Then once that render happens and those states are updated then the second useEffect is called because it's watching for those state changes. That is fine and doesn't cause another render  except that the function called in the second useEffect also sets state which will cause another render.